# How Can I get Multi Json Response without merge JSON In Android with node js using Volley?

Tags: android, json, node.js, express, android-volley

I'm using Android studio with Nodejs. To get data, I want to get Json from nodejs server using 'volley' At server( Nodejs, Express)  delivery Tow JSon

```
                res.write(JSON.stringify(results));
                res.write(JSON.stringify(hot));
```

i want to get these Jsons from server to Android but fail... i can get only one JSON which is delivered first , this one

```
     res.write(JSON.stringify(results));
```

how can i get two JSON ?? without merge JSON

```
public void onButton1Clicked(View v){

    String url=editText.getText().toString();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                println(response);
                JSONArray jarray= new JSONArray(response);

                for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject Jobs=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title=Jobs.getString("title");
                    String content=Jobs.getString("content");

                    println(" title : " + title);
                    println(" content : " + content);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                println("에러남!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    println("error!@@@");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            return params;
        }
    };
    request.setShouldCache(false);
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    println("웹 서버에 요청함 : "+url);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just send one response with different key => value pairs?

Comment: the content what i deliver is umm... different content and at first i try merge each JSON but each JSON doesn't have a key.. so if merge i cant distinguish which one is first content and other....  merge is good but is there a solution give key value to each JSON content?

Comment: `res.json({results, hot})`...?

Comment: something like the above should be fine :)